# Was the spider that bit Peter Parker in the Sam Raimi universe radioactive?

Tags: marvel, spider-man, spider-man-2002

In Sam Raimi's Spider-Man (2002), it's revealed during the class trip scene to Oscorp Labs that the spider that bit Peter Parker is an entirely new species created by combining all the best genetic traits of lab spiders. This spider was just one of 15 super-spiders in the same tank, which escaped for at least long enough to bite Peter.

I don't recall any dialogue about the spider *also* being radioactive. Was this spider radioactive as well as being a genetic hybrid? If it wasn't at all radioactive, how does the Raimi universe explain Spider-Man gaining powers by being bitten by it?

Comment: [Listen bud, he's got radioactive blood.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I-qMBS1frkM)

Comment: Did we ever get a clear explanation of how the comics Spider-Man gained powers from a _radioactive_ spider?

Comment: @LogicDictates - Step 1) Radioactive spider. Step 2) ??? Step 3) Superpowers!

Comment: Just [imagine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bananaman) if he was bitten by [a radioactive banana](https://blog.xkcd.com/2011/04/26/radiation-chart-update/) instead. And then what if the banana had previous been bitten by [a spider](https://www.buglife.org.uk/blog/brazilian-wandering-spider-in-bananas-fact-or-fiction/)? The movies really did a very poor job of exploring all these storytelling possibilities.

Comment: Right, here we go — all other things being equal, the spider was [as radioactive as usual](https://slate.com/technology/2012/07/spider-man-what-happens-if-you-get-bitten-by-a-radioactive-spider.html).

Comment: @Prometheus  Your question is flawed.  A non radioactive spider will have exactly as much chance as a radioactive spider of turning someone into a superhero - zero.

Comment: TVTropes calles this [Genetic Engineering Is The New Nuke](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/GeneticEngineeringIsTheNewNuke).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**There is no indication the spider that bit Peter was radioactive. It was a genetically-engineered super-spider.**

The Oscorp tour guide advises:

> Over five painstaking years, Columbia's genetic research facility has fully mapped the genetic codes of each of these spiders.
> Armed with these DNA blueprints, we have now begun what was once thought impossible- inter-species genetic transmutation.
> This is the Recombination Lab, where we use synthesized transfer-RNA to encode an entirely new genome, combining genetic
> information from all three spiders into these ten genetically-designed super-spiders, the first mankind has ever produced.

Why Peter obtained special spider-like powers after being bitten by a genetically designed super-spider, like he fictionally might if he were instead explicitly bitten by a radioactive spider, is explained in about as much detail as if he might instead have gained strange powers by a radioactive spider instead of genetically designed spider.

Comment: Getting powers from a genetically altered spider seems *a little* more plausible than getting it from a radioactive one. On a scale of 1-10 it's a one rather than a zero

Comment: It just annoys me that if all things, they can’t even have film Spider-man get powers from radioactive spider. Make it a radioactive genetically designed super spider if genetic-design was Sony’s thing, but ffs make it radioactive. Dolph Lundgren’s Punisher had more association to his comic roots, lol.

Comment: You feel like the radioactivity of the spider is a really key component of Spider-Man? I always felt like radioactivity, back in 1962, presumably still had the balance between being an actual-real-life-science-thing, while not being generally well-understood by regular people, to serve as vaguely believable source for fantastic abilities (like "chemistry" did with Frankenstein's monster  back in the 1800s). Genetic engineering felt like a decent fit to me in 2002.

Comment: @Valorum:   I would rate it a little more than 1/10.   Maybe 2/10.   Like it's not at all implausible that you could get a human to express spider-web-like proteins in their sweat or something from horizontal gene transfer.

Comment: @PaulDWaite I mean it’s no Uncle Ben dying level of necessary origin elements, but it’s one of those annoying things for me. And in this case, it was unnecessary: changing one scientific technogibberish excuse for another.

Comment: @SillybutTrue: sure, although the previous scientific technogibberish was a bit more outdated. 2002 audiences probably would have wondered why he didn't just get cancer, and [we don't really want to get into all that](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spider-Man%3A_Reign).

Comment: Indeed. Origins constantly change, as time progresses, and audiences become more familiar. You're not likely to see a Fantastic Four adaptation where they're empowered while attempting to beat the Russians to the Moon, for instance.

Comment: @notovny What if the Fantastic Four had been bitten by _radioactive_ cosmic rays? Sadly, we'll never know.

Comment: That we’re more likely to see a Fantastic Four adaptation where they get their powers from a quantum gate instead of space is no consolation, though.

Comment: Honestly, I'd be fine with Peter Parker being at the Fantastic Four teleportation experiment and being bitten by a spider that was exposed to the weird energies released.  For me, the core parts of the empowering are: 1) It's a cutting-edge scientific experiment that someone else was doing. 2) A spider was directly affected, and bit Peter Parker. 3) It's a coincidence that Peter Parker was there at the time; the spider could have bitten anyone.